# how to get errors from reducers in subscription error block

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using ngrx stores and calling an API inside effects and I want to get the error in the subcription of one action if api fails

example

```
this.store.pipe(select(economicEntriesReducer.getEconomicEntries)).subscribe(
    (response) => { // getting response here if api in effect is successful}
    (error) => { // how do i make it work });
```

I am returning the state from reducers

export const getEconomicSupplierGroups = createSelector(
    getEconomicEntriesState,
    state => {
        return state;
    }
);

and handing the call like this in effects

```
return this.httpService.get('economic/entries').pipe(map(
    (response: Supplier[]) => {
        return new economicEntriesActions.GetEntriesSuccess(<Supplier[]>response);
    }),
    catchError(error => of(new economicEntriesActions.GetEntriesError(error)))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducers and selectors shouldn't throw errors.

Instead you should create a `getErrors` selector if you want to do something with the error.
More info at [Handling Error States with NgRx](https://blog.angularindepth.com/handling-error-states-with-ngrx-6b16f6d12a08)